# How to make an accurate search from two column in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am creating a search of First_name And Last_name from my database whereby the user inputs what he wants to find in a field and my php script will search the name that looks like those name.

So i did

```
$q=addslashes($_REQUEST['q']);

$q =mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $q);

//In order to search word by word i explode the string
$notre_tableau=explode(',',$q);

//I count the string in order to search each word
$compter_tableau=count($notre_tableau);




$req_search = "SELECT   first_name, last_name 

FROM  mytable

WHERE ";


//Now i read the array and search for each word
for ($i = 0; $i < $compter_tableau; $i++) 
{
$notremotchercher=trim($notre_tableau["$i"]);


if($i==$compter_tableau) { $liaison="AND"; } else { $liaison=""; }

if($i!=0) { $debutliaison="AND"; } else { $debutliaison=""; }

//I search only if the string is not empty

if($notremotchercher!='')
{
$req_search .= "$debutliaison (first_name LIKE '%$notremotchercher%' OR last_name LIKE '%$notremotchercher%')  $liaison";
}


}

//Now i proceed with my search
$requete=mysqli_query($connection, "$req_search ORDER BY id  DESC LIMIT 20  ") or die(mysqli_error($connection));
```

So if someone's first Name are is Jennifer Jane and last name is DOE, for example, if i input in Jennifer (only Jennifer) it works,
and if i Input in Jennifer Jane  it works,
 and if i input in DOE, it also works.

The above code will display something like this for a search based on Jennifer

```
SELECT  first_name, last_name  FROM mytable WHERE    (first_name LIKE '%Jennifer%' OR last_name LIKE '%Jennifer%')
```

Therefore I get a result

**Problem**
If I input in **Jane Jennifer**, it does NOT work
Also if i Input in **Jennifer DOE**, it does not work. Please how to make it work for Both column knowing that i can not tell what the user will input in First ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to split up the words in the search. So if the search term was "Jane doe"...

```
<?php
     $search_phrase = "Jane Doe";
     $terms = explode(" ",$search_phrase);
     $query = "SELECT first_name, last_name  from myTable WHERE ";

     for($i=0;$i<count($terms);$i++){
         if($i!=0)
            $query.=" OR ";
         $query.=" (first_name LIKE '%".$terms[$i]."%' OR last_name LIKE '%".$terms[$i]."%')";
     }

     echo $query; //Should produce "SELECT first_name, last_name  from myTable WHERE (first_name LIKE '%Jane%' OR last_name LIKE '%Jane%') OR (first_name LIKE '%Doe%' OR last_name LIKE '%Doe%')"


?>
```

You can use something like above and taylor it to your needs, like only searching for the last name using the second part of the term, etc..

Answer (score 1):

You explode your search string:

```
$searhStr     = 'Jane Jennifer';
$searchSplits = array(' ',',','.','-','?','!',"\n");
$searchArray  = explode($searchSplits,$searhStr);
```

and then you look for each word in the array:

```
forach ($searchArray as $searchWord)
{
  $queryParts[] = "first_name LIKE '%{$searchWord}%'";
  $queryParts[] = "prenom LIKE '%{$searchWord}%'";
}
$query = 'SELECT first_name, 
                 last_name  
          FROM mytable 
          WHERE '.implode(' OR ',$queryParts);
```

It is never to late to learn new things. Have a look at how MySQL can help you doing searches:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: What about prepared statements?